# C++11 fgetc outputs a 0 to my file when used in "r+b" mode

Tags: c++, file

I'm writing some file IO primitives for an interpreter for a language, and I'm having problems with strange behaviour of `fgetc`.

Here is a reproducible example (at least on windows, haven't tried on linux):

```
FILE* f = fopen("reprod.txt", "r+b");
fputc('a', f);
fputc('a', f);
```

Starting with an empty reprod.txt file, this code will write two `'a'`s to the file. This is fine. However, the following code does something different (again starting with an empty file):

```
FILE* f = fopen("reprod.txt", "r+b");
fputc('a', f);
fputc('a', f);
fgetc(f);
```

I would have expected `fgetc` to return `EOF` here (it does not). Instead it returns `0` and an extra `0` byte is written into my file!

I've read the manual page for `fgetc` and it doesn't mention anything about this! For reference, I'm compiling in C++11 with g++ on Windows 10. Is there a good reason why this is happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Update: it works fine on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `fopen` indicates that when opening a file in an update mode (`"+"`), a call must be made to `fflush`, `fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind` after performing a write, before performing a subsequent read. Couldn't find any word on if it's defined what happens if you fail to do so. I tried comparing this fix vs. no fix in Visual Studio 2017, and it seemed to correct the unwanted behavior

Comment: Ah thanks, I had originally assumed that it made that call for you when I first read that!